# Website (Table) looks fine in Firefox but not Chrome/Edge

Tags: html, css, sql, firefox, html-table

Below is some of the code for my website. The table works perfectly on Firefox but when I open it in either Chrome or Edge it squishes the picture up, I'm not too sure what it is that's making it do this.

This is how it looks on Firefox:

[image: This is how it looks on Firefox]

This is how it looks on Chrome/Edge:

[image: This is how it looks on Chrome/Edge]

```
    <div class="row">
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "music";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM music_tbl";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo "<table class='table-hover mainTable' border='1'>";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
 echo "<tr><td><img width='80%' height='80%'src=/Music_Player/songimages/". $row['album_cover_url'].">" .
     "</td><td>" . $row["track_name"] .
     "</td><td>" . $row["singers"] .
     "</td><td>" . $row["album_name"] .   
     "</td><td>" . $row["trackID"] . 
    "</td><td><a href=index.php?trackID=". $row["trackID"] ."><img src=playButton.png class='playB'></a>
     </td></tr>";
     }
    echo "</table>";             
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Below is my CSS:

```
    .mainTable {
position: relative;
right: 20%;
margin:0 auto;
font-size: 99%;
text-align: center; 
border: 1px solid #b3b3b3;
border-collapse: collapse;
max-width: 45%;
max-height: 100%;
font-family: verdana;
margin-bottom: -1px;
top: 200px;
    }
    tr, td {
border-collapse: collapse;
padding: 5px;
max-width: 650px;
    }
    .albums {
padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: "</td><td><a href=index.php?trackID=". $row["trackID"] ."><img src=playButton.png class='playB'></a>
     </td></tr>";

Comment: !! Sorry this is what I meant to add:

I have a dim recollection looming out of my past when I was a younger man that this is a bizarre PHP quirk...

Your last line:

"</td><td><a href=index.php?trackID=". $row["trackID"] ."><img src=playButton.png class='playB'></a>
     </td></tr>";

looks like it has a line/paragraph break between </a> and </td></tr>

Try removing it - some browsers may not like it.

I'm sure I've come across something like this in the past (but it's just a suggestion).

Comment: Nope, still the same, Thanks tho!

Comment: Hmm... OK - I'm still thinking... trying to remember what that quirk was. There doesn't seem too much wrong with your table-generating code (we see it works in Firefox) but it looks to me like the </tr> or </td> bits aren't getting correctly picked up by Chrome / Edge. Is there a web version of this I could look at so as to see the resulting source code?

Comment: Right - just looked up a few old bits of code ... so, I'm now going further - I think it is not wise to include *ANY* line breaks in a PHP echo statement. Either break it down into smaller echo statements, or, better still, build a $str variable holding your table structure, and then echo that.

Comment: No I'm not hosting it anywhere, it's being previewed through XAMPP

Comment: @J.Green1997 Can you try to make a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? What you're showing here is impossible to debug. The only thing I can see is the `height='80%'` on the images. 80% of what? Neither the table, nor the table cells have heights defined. (max-height doesn't count.)